# How can I use variables in statements with Python?

Tags: python, string, class

```
sname = "example"
some_class.<sname>.do_stuff()
```

`sname` is the name of a subclass in `some_class`. Is it possible to dynamically reference the string in my call, so `some_class.example.do_stuff()` is called?

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the `getattr()` builtin:

```
getattr(some_class, sname).do_stuff()
```